# Box/minipage with fixed size and fixed location

Tags: boxes, framed

I'm writing a thesis and I will be provided a standard front page by my school. The front page have cut-out area. On the next page I will show some detailed information about the thesis. I was provided a word template but I would rather not use Word.

[image: Cut out]

So I'm looking for some method to create a non-framed fixed size box in a fixed location. The box should be 60mm x 110mm with left top corner located at (140mm,50mm). (The A4 Paper is 297mm x 210mm).

I will have to be able to modify the text by size, bold, centering horizontally and vertically inside the box.

I have taken a look at:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    %\parbox[position][height][inner-pos]{width}{text}
    %\mbox{text}
    %\makebox[width][pos]{text}
    %\fbox{text}
    %\framebox[width][pos]{text}

\end{document}
```

But they don't seem to work the way I want. I'm also thinking if this would be possible with minipages?

Comment: Is the form really rectangular or with rounded edges?

Comment: The front page cut-out is actually oval, but I would only need a rectangular box for my text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `textpos` package allows for absolute (or relative) positioning) of content on a page -- here `absolute` is too be chosen.

The size and position values have to be specified as numbers only, i.e. without units. In order to inform `textpos` about the real dimensions, the lengths `\TPVertModule` and `\TPHorizModule` must be defined, here they are equal to `1mm` both.

The `tcolorbox` is just meant for quick setup of the box!

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1mm}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}

\newcommand{\myboxwidth}{110}
\newcommand{\myboxheight}{60}
\newcommand{\myboxposx}{50}
\newcommand{\myboxposy}{140}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{textblock}{\myboxwidth}(\myboxposx,\myboxposy)
  \noindent%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[left skip=0pt,width={\dimexpr\myboxwidth mm},boxrule=0pt,nobeforeafter,enhanced jigsaw,height={\dimexpr\myboxheight mm},colback=red]
  \end{tcolorbox}
\end{textblock}
\end{document}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice Christian, would you know a way to center the inserted text vertically? I've tried \vfill before and after text. I've tried \vspace*{\fill}. I've tried \begin{vplace}[0.5]text\end{vplace}.

Comment: @bjartmar: Do you mean the `\lipsum` text above the 'cut-out'?

Comment: No, I mean the text inside the textbox/colorbox you provided. I found it in the tcolorbox help. [halign=flush center, valign=center] does the trick. :)

Comment: @bjartmar: Yes, that's the code. `tcolorbox` is pretty smart ;-)

Comment: Yes, never heard of this package. Will come really handy! Thanks again. :)